# Rotate GameObject on Z axis while moving forward

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I have the following code, and it works 100% for a 3D game, but I can't get it to work for a 2D game.

What it is supposed to do, is once the object gets to the waypoint, it is supposed to rotate towards the new waypoint. What is actually happening is that it is rotating around the `x` and `y` axis, and not the z axis. What can I do to make it only rotate on the `z` axis? The object is supposed to turn as it moves forward based on the turn speed. It shouldn't be an instant turn, unless the turnspeed is a high number. But anyways, again I ask how do I get this code to only roate on the `z` axis?

```
void Update () {
    if(toWaypoint > -1){
        Vector3 targetDir = wayPoints[toWaypoint].position - transform.position;
        Vector3 newDir = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetDir, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDir);
    }
    if(!usePhysics && toWaypoint != -1){
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for:

```
void Update () {
    if(toWaypoint > -1){
        Vector3 vectorToTarget = wayPoints[toWaypoint].position - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(vectorToTarget.y, vectorToTarget.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        Quaternion q = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, q, Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed);
    }
    if(!usePhysics && toWaypoint != -1){
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look rotation is not dependable for 2D games as the forward axis is different. One workaround is to parent the sprite to an empty GameObject with the z axis (blue arrow) pointed in the direction that the sprite will be rotating.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using Unity3D, which leaves me wondering why you're messing around with the Z-axis in the first place if you're making a game in 2D editing mode. The Z-axis does literally nothing in that mode, unless you set your two axes to include it somehow. My suggestion to you is to switch to 2D editing if you haven't already, then use `Vector2`s instead of `Vector3`s.

Also, try using one of the other axes as your axis of rotation (`transform.right` or `.up` instead of `.forward`).